# Discord.py, member.status isn't working as it should

Tags: discord.py, bots, embed

```
@bot.tree.command(name="user", description="Shows some informations about the mentioned user.")
async def user(interaction: discord.Interaction, member:discord.Member=None):
  if member == None:
    member = interaction.user
  roles = [role for role in member.roles if role.name != "@everyone"]
  embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Details about the user, {member.name}",color=0xdaddd8, timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow())
  embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar) # Avatar Thumbnail
  embed.add_field(name=" Name", value = f"{member.name}#{member.discriminator}") # Embeds
  embed.add_field(name="️ Nickname", value = member.display_name)
  embed.add_field(name=" User ID", value = member.id)
  embed.add_field(name=" Created at", value = member.created_at.strftime("%D \n%I:%M %p"))
  embed.add_field(name=" Joined at", value = member.joined_at.strftime("%D \n%I:%M %p"))
  embed.add_field(name=" Status", value = member.status) #this line is'nt working as it should
  embed.add_field(name="❤️‍ Top role", value = member.top_role.mention)
  bot_status = "Yes, it is" if member.bot else "No, They'snt"
  embed.add_field(name=" Bot?", value = bot_status)
  embed.set_footer(text = interaction.user.name,icon_url = interaction.user.avatar)
  await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)
```

I made a User information command and this command shows every person offline even itself how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This is likely due to lack of intents.
Add in your code, under the intents you define:

```py
intents.members = True
intents.presences = True
```

Comment: I tried to do with using your solution 

(intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.presences = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents))

and it didnt worked, the bot keeped saying offline. And I tried to do with
(bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".",intents=discord.Intents.all())) 
and it didn't worked too. I thing the problem is'nt about intents.

Comment: Then could you please edit to show the whole code? That code works for me. Maybe try re-inviting your bot to the server with all the authorisations